# Profile views no longer updated?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, profile-page

I don't think my profile views are working since the update - has this been reported?

I've noticed that my profile views are frozen on my and my friends' *English Language & Usage* and *Stack Overflow* sites since the update.

Comment: On a particular site or all of them?

Comment: I've noticed it on English Language & Usage and Stack Overflow

Comment: I did not downvote, but you may want to incorporate that into your question to make it more specific.

Comment: I downvoted because the question has very low quality. There is no details or proof and the question is very narrow; it's a yes or no question

Comment: @PythonMaster, I'm not even sure this is the right place to report this but my anecdotal evidence is that since the update, my profile views are frozen, as are my friends' on these sites.

Comment: Are you expecting a lot of views from a lot of different places? Or are you expecting the number to count based on something else?

Comment: @random, when I check friends' profiles for new activity and reputation changes and they look at mine, the profile views used to go up by one view, accordingly.  Despite visits to our profiles, the view count has not changed since the update.

Comment: @PythonMaster This is the right place to report oddities/bugs/etc. We can't expect everyone to come in with hard proof and such since different people have different levels of technical ability. (p.s. I'm adding the "bug" tag so that someone can look into this next week and check if views are working as intended still.)

Comment: @KristinaLopez I'm pretty sure the profile view count only increases by 1 when it's visited by someone who's never visited it before.

Comment: @pacoverflow, I've seen my own visits to others' profiles actually up the number each time...again, prior to the update.

Comment: The profiles views are/should be cached, so I wouldn't trust the number going up every time you view someone's profile. Will look again next week just to be sure.

Comment: @AnnaLear For when you look at it next week: Looks like the `/users/ivc...` route only gets triggered if you view the activity tab, which might explain it.

Comment: @TimStone Hah. Yeah, that'd probably do it. Thanks for the heads up. :)

Comment: @KristinaLopez A few sites on SE still don't have the update (such as SciFi.SE).  If I hit refresh on user's profile 5 times in a row, should the view count increase by 5?  I don't see that happening on this user's profile on SciFi.SE: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/20774/richard

Comment: @AnnaLear Are site-specific bugs allowed here?  I had this question closed because it was about a bug on a specific site: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252000/software-recommendations-unanswered-tab-sorted-by-votes-is-not-sorted

Comment: @pacoverflow In general, site-specific bugs should be reported on the site's meta. If that's not possible (e.g. you don't have 5 rep required to post there), here is fine  as well. It looks like the main reason your report got closed is that it was no longer reproducible, though.

Comment: Hi Kristina. As a test, I just looked at your English.SE profile, and it lists your views as 2753 (very impressive!). Hopefully you'll see that reflected in your count, even if you have to wait for it to catch up. I didn't view the Activities page. If, as @Tim Stone suspects, that's necessary to trigger the count, perhaps you should write a separate post asking the count to be connected to views of the profile page, as that's where that statistic is located.

Comment: Thanks @Sue.  Actually my profile views have been at 2753 since the day of the profile page update.  If it worked as before, your visit to my profile should have bumped the number to 2754 but it didn't.

Comment: @pacoverflow, I just checked a friend's profile on the Seasoned Advice site which has not been updated to the new profile/activity page yet and when I refreshed the page, the profile views increased by one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We were only counting views on the activity tab.

This is now fixed and has been deployed across the network.

Thanks for reporting!

Comment: Strange, I visited Kristina Lopez's ELU profile yesterday - both the Profile and Activities tabs, and it stayed on 2753.

Comment: That was what I saw too, @pacoverflow, and thought that what was happening was that the visits to the Activity tab counted the visit but didn't push that to the "counter" on the Profile tab - or that there should now be a counter on the Activity tab, which there is not, currently.

Comment: @KristinaLopez I'm seeing 2762 visits on your ELU profile now. Is that as it should be? The system also just caught up with another user I was tracking. Looks like it's fixed. Thanks Oded!

Comment: Yes, @Sue, that seems right now - I usually get a couple/few per day.  I'd consider this fixed for ELU.  Thanks for checking!